# Remove element in nested loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, splice

I am writting a simple metaballs implementation in JS. I have an array of the metaballs and i iterate through all of them every frame, and for each one I check the distance to every other metaball and if they are close enough I need to merge them.

This is how I guess it could look, but I don't know how to properly remove the element from array and not break the loops.

```
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < points.length ; j++) {
        if(i != j) {
            if(distance < 10) {
                //remove one of the points using splice
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Well, what is `points`? Is it a "live" collection or static? If removing items from a collection while iterating is a problem, you could always store the items to be deleted in a `toDelete` collection and then iterate through that to delete them later.

Comment: Splice documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Examples

Comment: There's a good chance this is an O(n^3) algorithm because the timing of various remove functions might be bad. I say "might be" because the internal representation of JS arrays isn't clear in the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start your inner loop at `i + 1`.  You've already compared elements up to `i`, so there's no need to repeat, right?  That let's you get rid of your `if` statement as well.

Then, when you splice, decrement `j` so as to not skip the next element.

```
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < points.length ; j++) {
        if (distance(i, j) < 10) {
            points.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2715488 - Note that `splice()` always returns an array. If you want to use the removed element (as suggested by your need to do merge logic), you probably want to do `point = points.splice(j--, 1)[0];` to get it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems like a nice optimization, but in my case, when the metaballs are close to each other (but not close enough to merge) I need them to move closer. And with these loops, only one in the pair moves to the other one.

EDIT: nevermind I tired and did not really think about it, it works but need a little bit more code